# build an admin view of all available rules (rules module), a better rules UI

Tags: views, rules

is there a hook to build an admin view of all available rules (rules module) to build a better rules UI? it may be a table view, so we can apply filters and groups, and order them, like in weight, tag, event, etc. I have sites with 30-40 rules running and sometimes (too many) is difucult to figure out a map of a time-event-order-actions taken on site, seeking a better planification and manteinace. A view with the available elements could help a lot.
code is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any hooks but [rules_filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_filter) looks promising.